# DocuSign REST Phone Authentication with Template

Tags: docusignapi

I created templates in Docusign.
I call the REST API to generate a new enveloppe using these templates.
Code works fine:

- Signers get populated
- Fields get populated

But I cant get the Phone Authentication to work. I checked other code on the DocuSign website and here.
The only differences I can see:

- Different number of parameters: I tried with and without (recordVoicePrint=false,validateRecipProvidedNumber=false), it does'nt change the outcome
- I call a template instead of sending the Base64 doc like in other examples

Here is the JSON request:

```
{
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "value": "Some Name",
            "tabLabel": "CustName"
          },
          {
            "value": "315750.00",
            "tabLabel": "TotEqptCost"
          }
        ]
      },
      "roleName": "Signer",
      "requireIdLookup": true,
      "phoneAuthentication": {
        "senderProvidedNumbers": [
          "(222) 222-2222"
        ],
        "recipMayProvideNumber": false
      },
      "name": "James",
      "idCheckConfigurationName": "Phone Auth $",
      "email": "James@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "value": "Dome Name",
            "tabLabel": "CustName"
          },
          {
            "value": "315750.00",
            "tabLabel": "TotEqptCost"
          }
        ]
      },
      "roleName": "Signer2",
      "requireIdLookup": true,
      "phoneAuthentication": {
        "senderProvidedNumbers": [
          "+1 (111) 111-1111"
        ],
        "recipMayProvideNumber": false
      },
      "name": "Joe",
      "idCheckConfigurationName": "Phone Auth $",
      "email": "Joe@thing.com"
    }
  ],
  "templateId": "a315793d-896f-41b4-9c61-dfc6873bc6f3",
  "status": "created",
  "emailSubject": "Testing"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by using the Composite Templates. See code below.

```
{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "1",
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "James@gmail.com",
                "name": "James",
                "roleName": "Signer",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "requireIdLookup": true,
                "phoneAuthentication": {
                  "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                    "(222) 222-2222"
                  ],
                  "recipMayProvideNumber": false
                },
                "idCheckConfigurationName": "Phone Auth $",
                "tabs": {
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "value": "Some Name",
                      "tabLabel": "CustName"
                    },
                    {
                      "value": "315750.00",
                      "tabLabel": "TotEqptCost"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "John@company.com",
                "name": "John",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "requireIdLookup": true,
                "phoneAuthentication": {
                  "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                    "(222) 222-2222"
                  ],
                  "recipMayProvideNumber": false
                },
                "idCheckConfigurationName": "Phone Auth $",
                "roleName": "Signer2",
                "tabs": {
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "value": "Some Name",
                      "tabLabel": "CustName"
                    },
                    {
                      "value": "315750.00",
                      "tabLabel": "TotEqptCost"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "a315793d-896f-41b4-9c61-dfc6873bc6f3"
        }
      ]
    },

  ],
  "status": "created",
  "emailSubject": "Testing"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are entering phone number in wrong format, try below json snippet:

```
{
    "signers": [
        {
            "name": "Test Name",
            "email": "testemail+name@gmail.com",
            "roleName": "Signer 1",
            "routingOrder": 1,
            "recipientId": "1",
            "requireIdLookup": true,
            "idCheckConfigurationName": "Phone Auth $",
            "phoneAuthentication": {
                "recipMayProvideNumber": false,
                "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                    "+18889619998"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```